# How to exclude an option that have reached capacity from the form deployed using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, html-select

I created a web form using Google Apps Script that has options with capacity.

In the following example, there is a question to ask visitors to choose cheesecake or chocolate cake. Suppose that I have only two pieces of cheesecake and three pieces of chocolate cake, and if two visitors has already choose the cheesecake, I want to remove the option of cheesecake from the form and make that option invisible and thus unselectable, showing the option of chocolate cake only.

Then, how should I implement such a `select` question whose options have capacity using Google Apps Script?

Note but I want to create a custom web form, and that this time **I do NOT use Google Forms** for that purpose.

### EDIT

The following link will show how this programme saves data on a spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nE1yL24HamfbAbeRjoQV6SE0ecq6rCx1WlbQZ8N8R0/edit?usp=sharing

## index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form class="" action="<?!= getScriptUrl(); ?>" method="post">
      <div>
        <h1 id="Question">
          Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
        </h1>

          <select id="" name="cake" class="form-control">
            <option value="cheesecake">cheesecake</option>
            <option value="chocolate_cake">chocolate_cake</option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

## code.gs

```javascript
function doGet(){

 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();

}

function getScriptUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
  return url;
}

function doPost(e){

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11nE1yL24HamfbAbeRjoQV6SE0ecq6rCx1WlbQZ8N8R0").getSheets()[0];

  sh.appendRow([String(e.parameters.cake)]);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Thank you!</b>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an option based on quantity, then you should save the quantity of each cake to a Sheet.

### Here I modified your code and added some features:

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function getScriptUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  Logger.log(url);
  return url;
}

function doPost(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("insert sheet id here");
  var sh1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh1.appendRow([String(e.parameters.cake)]);

  //update Inventory
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var row = sh.createTextFinder(e.parameters.cake).findNext().getRow();
  var range = sh.getRange(row, 2);
  var data = range.getValue();
  range.setValue(parseInt(data - 1))

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Thank you!</b>'); 
  
}

function getAvailableFlavors(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("insert sheet id here");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var data =  sh.getRange(2, 1, 2, 2).getValues();
  var filtered = data.filter(arr =>  arr[1] > 0 || arr[1] != ''); //remove flavor to array if quantity is 0 or empty
  return filtered;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body onload="addOptions()">   <!--Execute addOptions function immediately after a page has been loaded-->
    <form class="" action="<?!= getScriptUrl(); ?>" method="post">
      <div>
        <h1 id="Question">
          Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
        </h1>
          <select id="dropdownList" name="cake" class="form-control"> 
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    function addOptions() {
      /*This will call server-side Apps Script function getAvailableFlavors and if it is successful, 
      it will pass the return value to function addListValues which will add options to the drop down menu*/
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(addListValues)
        .getAvailableFlavors();
    }

    function addListValues(values) { 
      //Add options to drop down menu using the values of parameter 'values'.     
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = values[i][0];
        option.value = values[i][0];
        var select = document.getElementById("dropdownList");
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
    }

    function onFailure(err) {
      alert('Error: ' + err.message);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Here I created a sheet named "**Inventory**":

[image]

and each time a person orders a cake, the quantity is reduced by 1.

[image]

When the quantity of cake reaches 0, the script will remove the cheesecake from the drop down list:

[image]

Note: You can copy and paste the code above but you need a Sheet named Inventory with the same content and format from my example above.

### References:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your current situation and goal are as follows.

- Your HTML is included in the Google Apps Script project.
- You want to retrieve the values from the Spreadsheet and show them in the dropdown list.
- For example, there are two pieces of cheesecake. When an user selects a cheesecake and submit it, you want to reduce `1` from cheesecake in the Spreadsheet.
- When the number of cheesecake is `0`, you don't want to select it.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

### Sample spreadsheet

In this script, in order to test, the following Spreadsheet is used. This sheet is the 1st tab of the Spreadsheet.

[image]

### Sample script

Please copy and paste the following scripts to the script editor. And, **please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps**.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

function updateValue(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, b]) => a == e ? [a, --b] : [a, b]);
  range.setValues(values);
  return values.map(([a, b]) => `<option value="${a}" ${b == 0 ? "disabled" : ""}>${a}</option>`).join("");
}

const doGet = () => {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
  var [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var v = values.map(([a, b]) => `<option value="${a}" ${b == 0 ? "disabled" : ""}>${a}</option>`).join("");
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html");
  html.values = v || "";
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side: `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <div>
      <h1 id="Question">
        Choose either cheesecake or chocolate cake.
      </h1>

      <select id="sampleSelect" name="cake" class="form-control">
        <?!= values ?>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="saveValue(this);return false;">
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    function saveValue(e) {
      const v = document.getElementById("form").cake.value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updated => {
        document.getElementById("sampleSelect").innerHTML = updated;
      }).updateValue(v);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Testing

Please access the deployed Web Apps reflected in the modified script. By this, you can see the dropdown list.

In this sample, cheesecake has 2. When you select a cheesecake and click the "Submit" button, the number of cheesecakes on the Spreadsheet becomes from 2 to 1. When you select cheesecake and click the button again, you can confirm that the option of cheesecake cannot be selected.

I thought that this might be your expected result.

### Note

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- This sample script is a simple script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)